# Content Security Policy Using Chrome and iframes

Tags: apache, google-chrome, security, iframe, policy

I have a web page that contains an iframe. The iframe is loaded with a URL call to the same server as the page. However, I get this, because I am apparently using a different port, 81:

```
Refused to frame 'http://my-same-server:81/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self' https://*".
```

I realize this is a Content Security Policy issue for newer Chrome browser versions, and know that I need to change an Apache header, but am not sure to what I would change it to allow the iframe to properly load. The URL cannot use HTTPS, otherwise there are no special conditions. Any help would be grand. Thank you.